# Every Time I try to do a post request in postman to http://localhost:8080/api/users

Tags: express

`userRoutes.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const { registerUser } = require("../controller/userController");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", registerUser);

module.exports = router;
```

`server.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const app = express();
// database
const connectDb = require("./db/db");
require("colors");
// router

const userRoute = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
dotenv.config();
connectDb();
app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/users", userRoute);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("");
  console.log(
    ` Running on Port ${port} in ${process.env.MODE} Mode `.yellow.inverse
  );
  console.log("");
});
```

`userController.js`:

```
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");

const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = req.body;  
  const exists = User.findOne({ email });
  if (exists) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("User Already Exists!");
  }

  const user = await User.create({ firstName, lastName, email, password });
  if (user) {
    res.status(200).json({
      firstName: user.firstName,
      lastName: user.lastName,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
    });
  } else {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error("User Not Created");
  }
});

module.exports = { registerUser };
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 118
        
                
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    
    at parse (D:\tutorial\shppingapp\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
                    
    at D:\tutorial\shppingapp\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
                    
    at invokeCallback (D:\tutorial\shppingapp\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
                    
    at done (D:\tutorial\shppingapp\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
                    
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (D:\tutorial\shppingapp\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
                    
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:406:35)
                    
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1331:12)
                    
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It seems that the payload which you send via Postman is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting this error because of not sending well req in postman you have to send req as your User Schema defined in the model and once send well formated in postman `body>text>json`...